# Transfer messages from direct message to specific channel using Java Discord API

Tags: java, discord, illegalstateexception, discord-jda

I want to make my bot in a server channel to say whatever an user dm it.

```java
public class PrivateMessage extends ListenerAdapter
{
    private TextChannel channel;

    @Override
    public void onReady(@NotNull ReadyEvent event)
    {
        channel = event.getJDA().getChannelById(TextChannel.class, 962688156942073887L);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent event)
    {
        if (event.isFromType(ChannelType.PRIVATE))
            channel.sendMessage(MessageCreateData.fromMessage(event.getMessage())).queue();
    }
}
```

At first it was working properly, until I dm it an image.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot build an empty message. You need at least one of content, embeds, components, or files
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. The **channel** is not declared properly. It does not have a type... In this case you should use either `TextChannel channel = (whatever)` or `Channel channel = (whatever)`
2. You get the error message because **channel** is not within the scope of
   `onMessageReceived()` You need to learn about scopes.
3. The `onReady()` will have no use in this case. Just as i mentioned before... Because of scopes.

Here is what your code should look like:

```
    @Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    if(event.isFromType(ChannelType.PRIVATE)){
        TextChannel textChannel = event.getJDA().getGuildById("1046510699809079448").getTextChannelById("1046510701184831540");
        textChannel.sendMessage(event.getMessage().getContentRaw()).queue();
    }
```

You need to get the **TextChannel** from a **Guild** by using their ID's.
Then you can get the message that was sent to the bot, by using **event.getMessage()** and getting its content via **.getContentRaw()**
and send it using **textChannel.sendMessage().queue()**

Comment: The channel variable belongs to PrivateMessage class, it is avaliable for both onReady() and onMessageReceived(), its scope is the entire class. And just as I said, if the message contains only raw content, it was working properly. There was an answer that actually solved my question, too bad that it was deleted. It suggested me that all I need is to use `String attachments = message.getAttachments().stream().map(Message.Attachment::getUrl).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));` to add images, it is working well now.